# XSD схема успешно валидируется, но logger выдает ошибку. cvc-elt.1

Tags: java, xml, валидация, xsd

Для задания нужно создать и провалидировать XML и XSD. Валидация проходит успешно, как через собственный SAX валидатор, так и через онлайн сервисы. Но, в логах у меня появляется такая ошибка:

`ERROR - 4 : 69 - cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beers'.`

Вроде все ссылки указаны правильно. Собственно сам XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beers xmlns="https://www.example.com/beers"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="https://www.example.com/beers beers.xsd">

    <beer>
        <name>Corona Extra</name>
        <type>light</type>
        <alcohol>true</alcohol>
        <manufacture>Grupo Modelo</manufacture>
        <ingredients>
            <ingredient>water</ingredient>
            <ingredient>barley malt</ingredient>
            <ingredient>corn</ingredient>
            <ingredient>rice</ingredient>
            <ingredient>ascorbic acid</ingredient>
            <ingredient>emulsifier E405</ingredient>
        </ingredients>
        <characteristics>
            <percentage>4.5</percentage>
            <transparency>0.65</transparency>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
            <calories>41.6</calories>
            <volume>0.355</volume>
            <material>glass</material>
        </characteristics>
    </beer>

    <beer>
        <name>Kostritzer</name>
        <type>dark</type>
        <alcohol>true</alcohol>
        <manufacture>Bitburger Braugruppe</manufacture>
        <ingredients>
            <ingredient>water</ingredient>
            <ingredient>barley malt</ingredient>
            <ingredient>hops</ingredient>
        </ingredients>
        <characteristics>
            <percentage>4.8</percentage>
            <transparency>0.2</transparency>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
            <calories>50</calories>
            <volume>0.5</volume>
            <material>glass</material>
        </characteristics>
    </beer>

    <beer>
        <name>Konig Pilsener</name>
        <type>lager</type>
        <alcohol>true</alcohol>
        <manufacture>Bitburger Braugruppe</manufacture>
        <ingredients>
            <ingredient>water</ingredient>
            <ingredient>barley malt</ingredient>
            <ingredient>hops</ingredient>
        </ingredients>
        <characteristics>
            <percentage>4.9</percentage>
            <transparency>0.6</transparency>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
            <calories>43</calories>
            <volume>0.5</volume>
            <material>iron</material>
        </characteristics>
    </beer>

    <beer>
        <name>Krombacher</name>
        <type>light</type>
        <alcohol>false</alcohol>
        <manufacture>Krombacher</manufacture>
        <ingredients>
            <ingredient>water</ingredient>
            <ingredient>malt</ingredient>
            <ingredient>hops</ingredient>
            <ingredient>maltose syrup</ingredient>
        </ingredients>
        <characteristics>
            <transparency>0.65</transparency>
            <filtered>true</filtered>
            <calories>26</calories>
            <volume>0.33</volume>
            <material>glass</material>
        </characteristics>
    </beer>

</beers>
```

И XSD схема:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="https://www.example.com/beers"
           xmlns="https://www.example.com/beers"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name="beers">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>

                <xs:element name="beer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>

                            <xs:element name="name">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z ]+"/>
                                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>

                            <xs:element name="type">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:enumeration value="light"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="dark"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="lager"/>
                                        <xs:enumeration value="live"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>

                            <xs:element name="alcohol" type="xs:boolean"/>

                            <xs:element name="manufacture">
                                <xs:simpleType>
                                    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                        <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z ]+"/>
                                        <xs:whiteSpace value="collapse"/>
                                    </xs:restriction>
                                </xs:simpleType>
                            </xs:element>

                            <xs:element name="ingredients">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="ingredient" type="xs:string" minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>

                            <xs:element name="characteristics">
                                <xs:complexType>
                                    <xs:sequence>
                                        <xs:element name="percentage" type="xs:decimal" minOccurs="0"/>
                                        <xs:element name="transparency" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                        <xs:element name="filtered" type="xs:boolean"/>
                                        <xs:element name="calories" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                        <xs:element name="volume" type="xs:decimal"/>
                                        <xs:element name="material">
                                            <xs:simpleType>
                                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="glass"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="plastic"/>
                                                    <xs:enumeration value="iron"/>
                                                </xs:restriction>
                                            </xs:simpleType>
                                        </xs:element>
                                    </xs:sequence>
                                </xs:complexType>
                            </xs:element>

                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>

            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Сам валидатор:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "src/main/resources/data/beers.xml";
        String schemaName = "src/main/resources/data/beers.xsd";
        String logName = "src/main/resources/logs/log.txt";
        Schema schema;
        String language = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
        try {
            schema = factory.newSchema(new File(schemaName));
            SAXParserFactory saxParserFactory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            saxParserFactory.setSchema(schema);
            SAXParser parser = saxParserFactory.newSAXParser();
            parser.parse(fileName, new BeersErrorHandler(logName));
            System.out.println(fileName + " is valid.");
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.err.println(fileName + " config error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.err.println(fileName + " SAX error: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("I/O error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переписал валидатор, проблема исчезла. Причину до конца не понял.
Решение:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String language = XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI;
        String fileName = "src/main/resources/data/beers.xml";
        String schemaName = "src/main/resources/data/beers.xsd";
        String logName = "src/main/resources/logs/log.txt";
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(language);
        File schemaLocation = new File(schemaName);
        try {
            Schema schema = factory.newSchema(schemaLocation);
            Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
            Source source = new StreamSource(fileName);
            BeersErrorHandler handler = new BeersErrorHandler(logName);
            validator.setErrorHandler(handler);
            validator.validate(source);
            System.out.println(fileName + " is valid.");
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.err.println("Validation " + fileName + " is not valid " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(fileName + "is not valid" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```